# Unexpected path after tilde (~/) resolution in .cshtml file

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Imagine the following piece of cshtml file:

```
<img src="~/img/image.jpg" />
```

And compare it to the following:

```
<img src="@("~/img/image.jpg")" />
```

I for one would expect the same result in both cases, however, the `~/` part is only resolved correctly (to the app root directory) in the first case. The second version ends up with 404 Not Found as the src resolves to `http://localhost:50453/~/img/image.jpg`.

Is this a bug or a feature? And if it is a feature then what is the logic behind its implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. When razor sees `~`, It will convert that to the application base root. But in your second example, you are passing the path to image as a string (including the `~`) and it will be rendered as a string itself.

You should be using  `src="~/img/image.jpg"`

Comment: I am in particular interested why is the order of evaluation as is, if there is a special reason for that. I.e. why razor first resolves tilde paths and only afterwards renders the @(...) into the resulting page.

Comment: Does it really matter ? Razor will give you the complete page to the browser at once.

Comment: It matters (to me), that's why I am asking this question. I just find it rather ugly in case I am constructing some more complex `src` paths and storing them in let say `tempVar` because then to achieve the desired effect I have to do `src="~/@tempVar"`, i.e. I cannot rely on `~/` being resolved if it is part of `tempVar`.

Comment: No it won't be a problem.You can do `"~/@yourVaribaleName/someImag.jpg"` and razor will take care of converting the the correct ~ to app base path. If your variable name contains ~ in it, It will be still added as a string. But why are you even having ~ in the temp variable. You should not as the built in `~` gives that.

Comment: I have ~ in my temp variable because I was expecting the second version from my original question to work :) hence the question - why it doesn't work. Or in other words - what was the motivation of authors behind razor to have the order of evaluation as is? I simply had a "magic string" of `~/Upload/Product` in many of my views, therefore I decided to extract it into globally accessible constant which and use it via @. However, afterwards all my images failed to load. Hope you now see my motivation to have tilde in `tempVar` and my disappoinment of it not being resolved by razor.